# White skinned sweet potato is too young to eat?

Tags: sweet-potato

It's spring here in Australia and a scrub turkey has just dug up my beautiful sweet potato patch and began pecking at the tubers underneath. I'm contemplating digging them up to eat and pulled one out to inspect. It looks relatively mature to my novice eyes, but the skin is white.

Does this mean it's immature? Or could it be a white-skinned variety?

If it is immature, is it still edible? Or is it unsafe to eat?

[image: possibly immature sweet potato]

Edit: We sliced and fried it and it was great and we are not dead. :)